# JavaScript constructor-function

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble achieving "OOP-like" functionality in JavaScript.

I want to draw bar charts from this:

```
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="400">Not supported content</canvas>       
<script>    
    var values = [20, 50, 80, 10, 90, 30, 10, 14, 67, 38];
    var linewidth = 3;
    var linecolor = "black";
    var fillcolors = ["red", "orange"]; 

    draw();

    function draw() {
        var cnv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var g = cnv.getContext("2d");
        g.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);       
        g.strokeStyle = linecolor;          
        g.lineWidth = linewidth;

        var width = cnv.width;
        var height = cnv.height - (linewidth);              
        var x = linewidth/2;
        var y = cnv.height - (linewidth/2);

        var scaleHeight = height/maxValue(values);
        var l = values.length;
        var barWidth = (width/l)*0.8;
        var spacing = (width/l)*0.2;        

        for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            g.beginPath();
            g.fillStyle = fillcolors[i%fillcolors.length];
            g.rect(x + (barWidth + spacing)*i, y, barWidth, -values[i]*scaleHeight);
            g.fill();
            g.stroke();         
        }
    }   

    function maxValue(arr) {
        var arrCopy = arr.slice(0);
        arrCopy.sort(function(a, b){return b-a;});
        return arrCopy[0];
    }  
</script>
</body>
```

Using this:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var myChart = new BarChart(myCanvas);
myChart.setValues([23, 45, 80, 99]);
myChart.setColors(["red","orange"]);
myChart.setLineWidth(6);
myChart.setLineColor("green");
```

Now, I have tried things like this:

```
function BarChart(cnv) {
var values = [20, 50, 80, 10, 90, 30, 10, 14, 67, 38];
var linewidth = 3;
var linecolor = "black";
var fillcolors = ["red", "orange"];

this.setValues = function(v) {
    values = v;
};

this.setColors = function(c) {
    fillcolors = c;
};

this.setLineWidth = function (l) {
    this.linewidth = l;
};

this.setLineColor = function(lc) {
    linecolor = lc;
};
```

To no avail...

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem?

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end of your constructor and you don't need to use `this.linewidth` on the `setLineWidth` function.

Comment: Having the new BarChart-object draw the chart with values from the set-functions.

Comment: Is there a reason on why you are adopting this pattern?

Comment: Missing } because I didn't include the draw() and maxValue() here for shortness sake. Fixed the 'this'-typo, but I still can't get the new values to apply. It draws the chart with the original lines, colors, etc.

Comment: @ludolover, well it depends on when you are calling `draw()`. If you are doing it from the constructor then yes... it will display the original style.

Comment: @MinusFour, calling draw from outside the constructor worked. Thanks!